# Controlling multiple songs with multiple buttons

Tags: flash, audio

I am trying to program songs to play when I press a button. I have six buttons and six songs; and I want different songs to play when I hit a different buttons. How do I write as3 coding that starts and plays each song when I hit a button, but also stops the previous song thats playing that's associated with the previous button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stopAll from the SoundMixer to cancel the play of ALL sounds from your flash script,

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

look at the API reference for more details:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

then you just play the song associated with the button, 
as for playing songs you can make use of some available open source mp3 players (if that is the format you want to play). One I found with the .fla file is located here:

http://hotpot.uvic.ca/howto/audio.htm (click on: start, then: I'm a programmer, just give me the code)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, optimised way of using different buttons to run different songs from your library.. Keep in mind, this is assuming they are both named in your library, and follow the convention "Song1", "Song2" etc..

```
var soundchannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel(); //an audio channel to use to play sounds
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handlesongs); // adds the event listener for mouse evens
function handlesongs(e:MouseEvent)
{
    if (e.target.name.indexOf("Song") >= 0) // if the button is a "Song" button
    {
        var songnumber = e.target.name.substr(4); // set the song number based on the button's name
        var getsong = getDefinitionByName("Song" + songnumber.toString()) as Class; // get the class of the song to play
        var songtoplay = new getsong(); // assign a variable to the song's class
        soundchannel.stop(); // stop all current sound
        soundchannel = songtoplay.play(); // play the selected song
    }
}
```

Also, your buttons must be named like so: "Song1", "Song2".

This solution might not be ideal if you're making a music player, but if you have only a few sounds then it is ideal as it is strongly optimised.

(Please note: Using big sound files will heavily increase the size of your .FLA file)

ALSO Note:
It is VERY simple to change this up so that all the songs are in an array, and you use the substring method above to play the song at a specific array index. This might be the best way to go about it.